Add Rule To .htaccess File To Allow Space In Url
I am using a php script file "oAuth.php" to handle google and ms oAuth. ms is working very fine. as it passing following example values to return url:
https://MyDomain.ext/oAuth.php?code=M.C546_SN1.2.U.xxxxxxxx-8bda-9e81-05e8-xxxxxxxxxxxx

but unfortunately google send values with spaces (not url encoded) like following example:

and that causes 403 error on my server. (I googled and i found that space in url caused 403 error)
so? how i can over come this issue? adding a rule (only for oAuth.php) to allow space in url or is there any better solution?
thanks in advance
best regards
Update-1:
As per suggeston from @shingo, i have checked the apache error logs and found following:
Matched phrase ".profile" at ARGS:scope. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/08_Global_Other.conf"] [line "57"] [id "210580"] [rev "2"] [msg "COMODO WAF: OS File Access Attempt|||F|2"] [data "Matched Data: .profile found within ARGS:scope: email profile https:/mail.google.com/ openid https:/www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https:/www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "Other"] [uri "/oAuth.php"]

so, i have searched and add following to .htaccess file, but still same error. what i am missing here?
<IfModule mod_security.d>
  <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == m#oAuth.php#">
    SecRuleRemoveById 210580
  </If>
</IfModule>


403 means forbidden, Apache should return 400 bad request instead. So if you saw 403, it means something else processed the request and returned 403.

@shingo, thanks a lot for your kind reply/response. please check my updated answer.

Run urlencode() on whatever google sends back to you, spaces will be replaced with a +
